# Tapestry5JSPEditorEclipse for the TML pages

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tapestry

I am using [Tapestry5JSPEditorForEclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5JSPEditorEclipse) to generate the TLD files by tapestry-tldgen Maven plugin. i have added entry in the project pom.xml. below is the entry for the reference.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>fr.exanpe</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-tldgen</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
         <dependencies> 
           <dependency> 
               <groupId>com.sun</groupId> 
               <artifactId>tools</artifactId> 
               <version>1.5.0</version> 
         </dependency> 
      </dependencies> 
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>tld-generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <configuration>
                <uri>http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd</uri>
                <rootPackage>net.awl.bfi.websuite</rootPackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

when i try to install the project in eclipse, i am getting below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal fr.exanpe:tapestry-tldgen:1.0.0:tld-generate (default) on project WebSuiteTerminalMonitoringTapestry: Execution default of goal fr.exanpe:tapestry-tldgen:1.0.0:tld-generate failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
```

Please help me to generate the TLD so i can use JSP Editor for TML  in Tapestry project.

Your help appricated.

Regards,
Mahendra Athneria

Answer (score 0):

The projects' [Frequently Asked Questions](http://exanpe.free.fr/tapestry-tldgen/faq.html) page reads:

> The compilation doesn't work on Eclipse. Why ?
>   It seems the m2eclipse
>   extension for Eclipse doesn't take into account the plexus
>   components.xml descriptor file. This is the reason why the project
>   doesn't run on Eclipse auto build, but does on command line. We are
>   trying to find a way to get through...

So, if you try `mvn package` on the command line, it might work.

EDIT: If you still have trouble, please try the newest version of the plugin: `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Hi @Jan i tried with mvn package. it is not working for me. i am getting below error. java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.N
oClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException

Comment: Hi @mahendra-athneria, I assume, that your project builds if you disable the plugin, right? If so, please try the newest version of the plugin. I have included `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` into my project, because I also had trouble with `1.0.0`.

Comment: hi @Jan i am not able to find out the 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT jar. could you please send me/share the link jar?

Comment: hi, sorry for my late response. I can just find 1.1.0 by now: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.exanpe/tapestry-tldgen/1.1.0 and haven't the SNAPSHOT version in my local repo. I can't say whether this version already solves your problem.